# Python convert list of dictionaries to dict of key, values as list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of objects as below :

```
avariable = [{'id':1,'color':'pink'},{'id':1,'color':'blue'},{'id':2,'color':'green'}]
```

I want to convert it to :

```
{
"1" : [{'id':1,'color':'pink'},{'id':1,'color':'blue'}],
"2" : [{'id':2,'color':'green'}]
}
```

How to achieve this output, please help.

Comment: Hint: use `groupby` from the itertools package. Don't forget to sort if needed

Comment: Hint: `itertools.groupby`, please indicate what you''ve done.

Comment: itertools.groupby works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the suggestions have spoken, you need `itertools.groupby` -

```
from itertools import groupby

avariable = [{'id':1,'color':'pink'},{'id':1,'color':'blue'},{'id':2,'color':'green'}]
groups = []  
uniquekeys = []  
for k, g in groupby(sorted(avariable, key=lambda x: x['id']), lambda x: x['id']): 
    # Store group iterator as a list 
    groups.append(list(g))        
    uniquekeys.append(k)

print({ str(i):j for i, j in zip(uniquekeys, groups) })
```

The output -

```
{'1': [{'id': 1, 'color': 'pink'}, {'id': 1, 'color': 'blue'}], '2': [{'id': 2,
'color': 'green'}]}
```

Comment: You should have waited for the OP's response, but anyway!

Comment: Sure, I meant  that the hints were enough for you, that's why no one gave the full answer and left it for you as you should have been able to figure it out by now, but since you were not giving any response, I thought that you have either figured it out and didn't remember or care to update us on it or you just abandoned the search for answer.

Answer (score 2):

Without using any additional libraries.

```
avariable = [{'id':1,'color':'pink'},{'id':1,'color':'blue'},{'id':2,'color':'green'}]

new_dict = {}
keys = set([i['id'] for i in avariable])

for key in keys:
    temp = []
    for l in avariable:
        if l['id'] == key:
            temp.append(l)
        new_dict[key] = temp


print(new_dict)
{1: [{'color': 'pink', 'id': 1}, {'color': 'blue', 'id': 1}],
 2: [{'color': 'green', 'id': 2}]}
```

one liner (dictionary comprehension):

```
new_dict = {key: [l for l in avariable if l['id'] == key] for key in set([i['id'] for i in avariable])}
```

Comment: itertools is [not an additional library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)